# How to make the panel recognise the right monitor as primary in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, panel, xrandr

I have a dual monitor setup and use ArandR to align the monitors correctly, so that the right monitor is the primary one. The code of xrandr is:

```
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP2 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --primary --mode 1920x1200 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI3 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off
```

I can put panels on the right (primary) monitor, but this monitor is number 2 in the panel setting.

The problem now is: When I switch off the monitor on the left then the panel recognises just one monitor and no panel is displayed on my primary monitor.